# How can I get/change the current typing language?

Tags: android

I want to make an app that allows the user to quickly change input language on his android phone...

I've searched Android Dev but I couldn't find the appropriate class... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you **can not change** the locale of the user from withing your application.

This is not possible until the date of this question.

**Swiping the spacebar** to change the locole (language) is a behavior due to the android's default soft keyboard.

It will not work ):

Comment: Are you sure? Third party soft keyboards can change the input languages using gestures...

Just to be clear: I don't want to change tha language of the interface. Just the typing.

Comment: You mean by swiping on the spacebar?

Comment: Yes, that. All I want to do is add this functionality on a hard keyboard using hotkeys.

Comment: Well this sucks... :( 
Thanks for your time!